# ColdFusion 9 application timeout issue

Tags: coldfusion, timeout, coldfusion-9, application.cfc

Application timeout is set to 10 hours.

```
<cfset THIS.ApplicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan( 0, 10, 0, 0 ) />
```

I've added cfdump in OnApplicationStart() method, and I am outputting timestamp (now()) in the txt file.

```
<cfdump var="#now()#" output="c:/app.txt">
```

In this txt file I see, that my application is restarted (OnApplicationStart() method invoked), every 20 minutes or so and 3 or 4 times in a row. 
I have approximately 200 users on the system. 
I would never noticed this if there were not log errors which are stating that my application vars are not defined, and they are. I can not repeat this bug in the local enviroment.

I also added this block of code in the OnRequestStart() method in application.cfc:

```
        <cfif structIsEmpty(application)>
        <cflock scope = "Application" timeout = "30" type = "Exclusive"> 
            <cfset StructClear(application)/>
            <cfset THIS.OnApplicationStart() />
        </cflock>
    </cfif>
```

Please help!

Comment: Check the log file `cfusion-out.log` in the `\JRun4\logs\` directory for errors. I am curious if your ColdFusion service is restarting for some reason.

Comment: Agree with @Miguel-F. Additionally, you should not be "restarting" your application the way you are (by just re-running the `onApplicationStart()` event handler). You should be using `applicationStop()` to force the application to actually stop/start. Reading: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2012/07/difference-between-events-and-event.html

Comment: OK, guys. I tried the applicationStop(). I initialized application afterword and immediately got error upon initialization, which says that one application var is not defined. But after I refresh everything works. I will monitor activity in next two days. Thank You very much for your comments!

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge base [Miguel-F](/users/1636917/miguel-f) and [Adam Cameron](/users/894061/adam-cameron). You can also check the `application.log` file either from the log directory or from CFAdmin page to check for the application life cycle and get some information there. Also [Adam Cameron](/users/894061/adam-cameron) is right about restarting the application the right way using the `applicationStop()` function and then redirecting to home page to actually start the application automatically.

Comment: Seems like there's a bug with applicationStop() that causes issues when using it to restart an application. https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-3335568